# Чтение файла возле JAR

Tags: java, файловая-система

В одном каталоге с jar-файлом лежит properties файл, который нужно прочитать. Сейчас открываю файл так

```
InputStream file = new FileInputStream("my.properties");
```

но смущает, что, по сути, я открываю файл в **текущем** каталоге. Всегда ли текущий каталог будет каталогом где лежит jar? А если нет, то как правильно открывать файл?

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет, текущий каталог не всегда будет равен каталогу, в котором лежит jar. Получить каталог расположения jar-файла можно так:

```
File parent = new File(MyClass.class
                              .getProtectionDomain()
                              .getCodeSource()
                              .getLocation()
                              .toURI()).getParent();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String path = MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
path = new File(path).getParent();
InputStream file = new FileInputStream(path + "/my.properties");
```

Comment: А теперь положите jar-файл в каталог с кириллическим именем, содержащим пробелы.

Comment: Спасибо за поправку