# Java - чтение файла

Tags: java, файлы

Компилирую проект в jar-файл. Запускаю. В нем есть кнопка, сохраняющая переменные в файл, который создается в той же папке, что и сам jar-файл. Но когда я пытаюсь произвести чтение из этого файла, ничего не срабатывает. Вот начало кода чтения из файла:

```
public void loadAll(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    String path = Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
    String decodedPath = URLDecoder.decode(path, "UTF-8");

    try(FileReader reader = new FileReader(decodedPath+"/save.txt"))
    { //...
```

т.к. прописав обычный путь файл, jar не находит этот текстовик, тогда здесь я получил путь jar'a, но все равно не работает. Как дать понять jar'у, что файл находится вместе с ним в той же папке?

Comment: Попробуйте определить текущую папку.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Чтение файла возле JAR](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/850264/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%b5-jar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При сборке проекта мавеном, обнаружил, что путь, получаемый указанным Вами способом выдает путь вместе с самим джарником:

```
/patch/to/jar/target/SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Чтоб корректно получить путь к директории с `jar` следует добавить следующие строки:

```
    String patch = GlobalKeyboardExample.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
    File file = new File(patch);
    String jarPath = file.getCanonicalPath().toString();
    String jarDir = jarPath.substring( 0, jarPath.lastIndexOf( File.separator ));
```

`javaDir` содержит:

```
/patch/to/jar/target/
```

его и используйте в дальнейшей работе (не забьваем про слеш)

```
String decodedPath = URLDecoder.decode(javadir, "UTF-8");

try(FileReader reader = new FileReader(decodedPath+"save.txt"))
```

Comment: Директорию до этого я не указывал, все равно не работало. Я попробую Ваш вариант, спасибо!

Comment: Расскажете, или вышло

Comment: Вот, второй способ сработал! Большое спасибо)

Comment: Всегда пожалуста! только отметьте ответ, как решение вопроса. Если не трудно

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте как-то так:

```
File file = new File(new File(MainClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getFile()).getParentFile(), "file.txt");
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```