# Чтение файла возле JAR при работе со spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, файловая-система, jar

Задача: В одном каталоге с jar-файлом лежит properties файл, который нужно прочитать.

Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/850278/221228) мне посоветовали такой код

```
URI uri = clazz.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI();
String path = new File(uri).getParent();
```

Все отлично работало, пока я не связался со spring-boot.

В случае обычного jar uri возвращается в виде `file:/path/name-of-jar.jar` и все работает. Но при использовании spring-boot адрес получается другой `jar:file:/path/name-of-jar.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/` и последующий вызов

```
new File(uri)
```

валится с ошибкой

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical

Это как-то лечится? Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46666900/5376639) советуют просто обрезать строку до нужного вида. Но как-то метод мне не очень нравится

Comment: а этот properties файл нельзя положить в resources?

Comment: @Komdosh Нет. Там лежат настройки подключения к базе и они должны быть редактируемыми

Comment: а зачем? Может вам нужно использовать профили в spring?

Comment: @Komdosh Это независимая библиотека, которая о spring ничего не знает

Comment: попробуйте так https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46657181/how-to-get-spring-boot-application-jar-parent-folder-path-dinamically/46666900

Comment: @Komdosh Это я видел. И ссылка на этот ответ у меня в вопросе

Comment: @keekkenen Можете оформить в виде ответа? С учетом того, что библиотека, которой нужен внешний файл, упакована в отдельный jar и подключается к основному проекту через dependencies

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46657181/5376639

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получился такой код

```
public static String getParentRealPath(URI uri) throws URISyntaxException {
    if (!"jar".equals(uri.getScheme()))
        return new File(uri).getParent();
    do {
        uri = new URI(uri.getSchemeSpecificPart());
    } while ("jar".equals(uri.getScheme()));
    File file = new File(uri);
    do {
        while (!file.getName().endsWith(".jar!"))
            file = file.getParentFile();
        String path = file.toURI().toString();
        uri = new URI(path.substring(0, path.length() - 1));
        file = new File(uri);
    } while (!file.exists());
    return file.getParent();
}

URI uri = clazz.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI();
System.out.println(getParentRealPath(uri));
```

Answer (score 0):

Может библиотека и не знает о спринг, но спринг-то о ней точно знает.

По моему можно создать класс с `@Configuration` аннотацией, ему же добавить `@PropertySource`, в которой правильно прописать путь к внешнему файлу. Этот класс через `@Value`("${какой-то-ключ-из-проперти-файла}") сможет получить значения в поля этого класса, в этом же классе создать методы с `@Bean` аннотацией, которые создадут объекты вашей библиотеки с использование значений из проперти файла.